# Why does MultiSubnetFailover keep trying to connect to the inactive IP?

Tags: alwayson, availability

I am trying to use MultiSubnetFailover and it doesn't seem to be able to decide which IP to use.
Setup:
Client Connection String: MultiSubnetFailover=True

Server: Get-ClusterResource -Cluster  -Name  | Set-ClusterParameter -Name RegisterAllProvidersIP 1

Now when I work with this and SQL 2016 it works fine.

When I try it with SQL 2019 or SQL 2022 It retrieves both addresses and connects to the proper address but then keeps trying to connect to the inactive IP.
This is in turn causing contention that is messing up the server operation.

Does anyone have any ideas where I can look to solve this?

I am not sure what else I can do with this.